# How do I make a recursive jQuery template (tmpl) availbe outside of my plugin?

Tags: jquery, recursion, jquery-templates, requirejs

I have a Json object that I'm dumping into a jQuery template (tmpl). It needs to be recursive because the Json object can be n-levels deep. This code works. However, if I wrap it in a function (it belongs in a jQuery plugin i'm writing), it stops working. To see what I mean simply uncomment the function wrapper in the Javascript.

Play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/dbme/tkdZg/6/

HTML:

```
<script id="evntTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">

{{if data.identifiers}}
<div id="${data.identifiers.id}" class="bsa-event">
    type: ${data.identifiers.type}<br />
    id: ${data.identifiers.id}<br />
    {{if children}}
        {{each(i, child) children}}
        <blockquote>
            <p>        
            {{if children}}
               {{tmpl(children) "evntTemplate"}}
            {{/if}}
            </p>
        </blockquote>
        {{/each}}
    {{/if}}  
</div>
{{/if}}
</script>
<div id="eventList"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
//(function ($) {
//    $.fn.SomePlugin = function() {
var movies = {
    "data": {
        "identifiers":{
            "type":0, "id":"makeunique_907827h"
        }
    },
    "children": {
        "data": {
            "identifiers": {
                "type":1, "id":"makeunique_716786g"
            }
        },
        "children": {
            "data": {
                "identifiers": {
                    "type":1, "id":"makeunique_234355g"
                }
            }
        }        
    }
};

/* Render the template with the data */
var evntTemplate = $( "#evntTemplate" ).template( "evntTemplate" );
$.tmpl(evntTemplate, movies).appendTo("#eventList");
    //};
//}( jQuery ));
```

More info: I'm using RequireJS to load the files and kick off the whole process. I think that's what's killing the scope. Here's the code for that:

```
require(["jquery", "jquery.tmpl", "jquery.someplugin"], function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('body').SomePlugin();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are not passing the jquery object as parameter to your function wrapper.

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tkdZg/3

Change it to:

```
(function($) {
var movies = {
    "data": {
        "identifiers":{
            "type":0, "id":"makeunique_907827h"
        }
    },
    "children": {
        "data": {
            "identifiers": {
                "type":1, "id":"makeunique_716786g"
            }
        },
        "children": {
            "data": {
                "identifiers": {
                    "type":1, "id":"makeunique_234355g"
                }
            }
        }        
    }
};

/* Render the template with the data */
var evntTemplate = $( "#evntTemplate" ).template( "evntTemplate" );
$.tmpl(evntTemplate, movies).appendTo("#eventList");
})($); //########################
```

Comment: Ok, you're right. But I'm using (jQuery). I updated the code and jsfiddle to reflect what I'm actually doing. It's not too much of a difference but I'm not sure that I understand how to make it work... I've used the exact syntax for creating plugins that is recommended on the jQuery plugin Authoring page.

Comment: @dbme: You forgot to call the plugin method. That's it. I have updated the jsfiddle post to include a call and it worked. Check @ http://jsfiddle.net/tkdZg/8/

Comment: You're right. Also simply removing the variable and letting the tmpl plugin define the scope of the template worked. Thank you!